# Getting value from all div with same class using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get the id's of all products that are in divs with the same class. My code is only giving me the first product's id.

Here is the `html` code

```
<td>
    <div class="b-sku">SKU: 123456</div>
</td>
<td>
    <div class="b-sku">SKU: 33333</div>
</td>
```

I created this `javascript` code to just fetch value

```
function (){
    var out0 = document.querySelector('.b-sku').textContent;
    var out1 = out0.replace(/SKU:/g, "");
    var out2 = out1.replace(/\s/g, '');
    return out2;
}
```

But this code is only returning `123456` and not `33333`
I would like to get both the ids in comma separated format like

```
['123456', '33333']
```

Please advise.

Comment: You need to loop through the `out0` NodeList

Comment: Is this code complete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## querySelectorAll

Instead of using `querySelector` use `querySelectorAll` to ge a `NodeList` of elements to parse.

```js
function getBSKU() {
  var bSku = document.querySelectorAll('.b-sku');
  return Array.prototype.map.call(bSku, function(node) {
    var out1 = node.textContent.replace(/SKU:/g, "");
    var out2 = out1.replace(/\s/g, '');
    return out2;
  });
}

console.log(getBSKU())
```

```html
<td>
  <div class="b-sku">SKU: 123456</div>
</td>
<td>
  <div class="b-sku">SKU: 33333</div>
</td>
```

And now you sort through the elements with the `Array` given

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short 1 line approach to get a new array with the format like ['123456', '33333'] using [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), and [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

**ES6 Version**

Using Array.from()

```
let out2 = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('b-sku'), el => el.textContent.replace(/SKU: /i,""))
```

Using Object.values()

```
let out2 = Object.values(document.getElementsByClassName('b-sku')).map(el => el.textContent.replace(/SKU: /i,""))
```

Using the spread operator(...) (fastest)

```
let out2 = [...document.getElementsByClassName('b-sku')].map(el => el.textContent.replace(/SKU: /i,""))
```

Performance Test: https://jsperf.com/spread-vs-array-from-1/1

Comment: `[...arrLike]` is a lot shorter than `Array.from(arrLike)`, and is [often faster](https://jsperf.com/spread-vs-array-from)

Comment: Good call, it is slightly faster. I think Array.from() is a little more clear though. I'll add your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.querySelectorAll()` instead of `.querySelector()`, which returns the first matching element only, spread element to convert `NodeList` to `Array`, `.map()` to return the array

```js
function replaceSKU() {
  var skus = document.querySelectorAll('.b-sku');
  return [...skus].map(function(el) {
    return el.textContent.replace(/SKU:|\s/g, "");
  })
}

console.log(replaceSKU())
```

```html
<td>
  <div class="b-sku">SKU: 123456</div>
</td>
<td>
  <div class="b-sku">SKU: 33333</div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.getElementsByClassName()` to get a list of all the elements that have the given class name, then remove the first five characters of each `innerHTML` and add the rest to the result list.

**Here is an example:**

```js
function returnID()
{
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('b-sku');
  var out = [];
  
  for(var i =0; i < elements.length; i++)
  { 
     out.push(elements[i].innerHTML.substr(5));
  }
  
  return out;
}

console.log( returnID() );
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
  <div class="b-sku">SKU: 123456</div>
  </td>
  <td>
  <div class="b-sku">SKU: 33333</div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `document.getElementsByClassName('some-class')` and loop through the nodes and create a list using their text content or inner text.

Comment: There should not be a "." at selector string

Answer (score -1):

You should use `document.querySelectorAll()`.

and map over them.

```
// Create an array from the NodeList, so we can use other array functions.
var elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.b-sku'));

// Basically a loop and setting the value to the ids
var ids = elements.map(element => {
      return element.textContent.replace(/SKU:|\s/g, "");
});


console.log(ids);
```