# How to get all values of input text which has certain class?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get all values of input text which has certain class.

For example:

```
<input type='text' class='aa'>
<input type='text' class='aa'>
<input type='text' class='aa'>
<input type='text' class='aa'>
```

Let's say I coded 4 input text with class `aa`.

How do I get all values of each input text using javascript?

Will be glad for your help!

Comment: you are probably looking for querySelectorAll() and an iterator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting value from all div with same class using pure javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48241572/getting-value-from-all-div-with-same-class-using-pure-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all text field value located in a specific class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758301/get-all-text-field-value-located-in-a-specific-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to target all the inputs:

> The Document method `querySelectorAll()` returns a static (not live) *NodeList* representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.

And `forEach()` to loop through them to get each input values to push into an array:

```js
document.getElementById('getValues').addEventListener('click', function(){
  var valueArr = [];
  document.querySelectorAll('.aa').forEach(function(el){
    valueArr.push(el.value);
  });
  console.log(valueArr);
});
```

```html
<input type='text' class='aa'>
<input type='text' class='aa'>
<input type='text' class='aa'>
<input type='text' class='aa'>

<button type="button" id="getValues">Get Values</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

With one line and some ES6 you can do it without any jQuery or whatever:

```
const values = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.aa'))
                    .map(input => input.value)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this with jQuery:

**html:**

```
<input type='text' value="1" class='aa'>
<input type='text' value="2" class='aa'>
<input type='text' value="3" class='aa'>
<input type='text' value="4" class='aa'>
```

**js:**

```
$('.aa').each(function(){
    // code here
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nicklev/Lw5qxsne/)**

Comment: you can do anything with each input inside `.each` function

Comment: @Mamun we trying to help here, and question starter choose the best answer, probably he need jquery, probably not, i'm just trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`getElementsByClassName`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp). It will return an array of elements with the class name.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("aa");
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    console.log(elements[i].value);
}
```